# Kubernetes on AWS with NGINX ingress controller and SSL termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, devops

Having issues configuring SSL termination in my Kubernetes cluster. Attempting to figure out best place for this to happen.

I have been able to get it working following the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/README.md) and then updating the ingress controller service to include the SSL certificate details using **service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert** annotation:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:...
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 80
```

I then have ingress rules and services setup similar to:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.foo.bar
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app1

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When going to `app1.foo.bar` I can see that:

- http requests are redirected to https
- the SSL certificate is correctly applied

Originally I was trying to apply the certificate to my individual app services. I could see the certificate being applied to the ELB in AWS but wasn't being passed through. So my question is:

Is this the correct configuration or is there a better solution?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest terminating SSL on the Nginx Ingress Controller exposed with ELB, and use kube-lego for automated SSL certificate management.

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx & 
https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego

Comment: Thank you - if you see my `ingress-nginx` service this is using the controller you've listed and also terminates SSL when passing requests through. Does this configuration look correct to you?

Comment: what you are trying to do here seems to bessl termination on ELB, and that is not what I suggested. Just put the ingress service as regular one, exposing ports 80 and 443 without any additional fancy stuff (proxy protocol aside, as it makes a lot of sense). Then your SSL termination will happen on NginX.